# Connecting to a hidden wireless network on Kubuntu

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kde, kubuntu

How can I connect to a hidden wireless network on Kubuntu? I have 9.10 64bit installed, and have the information for the network (e.g. SSID and key) because I've already connected to it on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be general issue with KDE's Network Manager and hidden wireless networks - you can see (and vote for!) the bug here:
 https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209464.

I also have the problem using Kubuntu (both 9.10 and now on 10.04 beta) and have found installing the network manager from Gnome/Ubuntu makes it connect. An even easier solution would of cause be to just start broadcasting the SSID (as far as I know it doesn't really add much protection anyway, but I can't configure the router at work).

Hope more people will vote for this bug and that someone will fix it!

Answer (score 5):

This maybe helps:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid name_of_the_hidden_essid
```

Things to note:

- `sudo` runs the command as an administrator.
- `iwconfig` allows you to configure the wireless interface.
- The identifier `wlan0` can be something like `eth1`, execute the `iwconfig` command for a list.
- `essid` is the name of the Extended Service Set Identification.

More information on `essid` can be found [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_%28802.11_network%29), and [`man iwconfig`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iwconfig8.html).

Answer (score 4):

Create the connection in connection manager, with all correct settings,

then in terminal:  (replace `hidden_ssid` with the actual SSID of the network)

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan essid *HIDDEN_SSID*
```

Then go back to network manager.  It should now show the hidden network.

Click on it to connect.

Comment: didn't do the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

Since this question seems popular, I want to provide an update:

In newer version of KDE (4.6+, as far as I know), this bug is now gone. You can connect to a hidden network just using the plasma widget. If you're on an old version of KDE, upgrading is probably the best bet--there are some other new features that make it worth it.

Comment: How to add wigit

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the network, you should enable the SSID. This [article @ Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/steriley/archive/2007/10/16/myth-vs-reality-wireless-ssids.aspx) explains why it's actually a *security vulnerability* to hide the SSID.

In short: it's easy to discover the SSID because as part of the standard, machines must broadcast the SSID in order to connect to it (so someone just has to listen for a machine that's already connected to reconnect)

The security vulnerability comes with this: "If the wireless APs are configured as non-broadcast, each of the 500 Windows XP or Windows Server 2003-based laptops would periodically advertise the enterprise’s wireless network name, regardless of their location (in the office, at a wireless hotspot, or at home)." ([Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726942.aspx))

A new part of the standard states that machines may refuse to connect to a router not broadcasting SSID.